# Update all steam games using steamcmd

Tags: steam

I would like to update all of my Steam games via the command line, so that everything is ready when I open Steam.

I was looking into it and I found the [steamcmd](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD) which gives an example to update counterstrike `app_update 740 validate`. To use this I would however first have some way of obtaining all of the IDs of the installed Steam games.

Comment: There is no official way with steamcmd

Comment: You can do something similar by using the Steam client, by enabling auto-updates and scheduling the updates to some stretch of hours of the day.